# Google Play - Android TV release type Installation Issues Rejection Notice

Tags: android

Context:

- Made a game in unity and did all the neccessary configurations for it to work on Android TV
- Built and then sideloaded said app onto my own android tv device.
- I am able to click on the app from the home screen and play it perfectly fine, without error

Problem:
After opting in for Android TV support in the google play console for my app. I have received a rejection email for the following reason:

---

During review, we detected the following eligibility issue and were unable to accept your app for Android TV:

```
Your app exhibits installation issues. Apps should run successfully when the user selects the application banner from the home screen.
    For example, upon testing your app we experienced installation issues and were unable to successfully evaluate it for Android TV.
    If your app is only intended for specific devices please include a disclaimer in your store listing
        You can refer to our Android TV overview for additional guidance.
```

---

The app works perfectly for me, but somehow doesnt work for google? I submitted an appeal, asking for more details on why the installation failed. They just sent me the exact same email they already sent me.

Questions:
Has anyone ever experienced this before, or know anything about this issue?
Is my app suppose to be searchable in the google play store at this point? Therefore shouldnt be sideloading it?

Please help, thanks for your time.

Comment: Build the release apk and install that.  It's likely something in your release build not present in the debug build.  Frequently (but not always) that's do to proguard configuration

Comment: i currently have c++ compiler configuration in unity project settings set to "master", but i can try release if this is what you are talking about